# CMS software for product showcase and comparison

Tags: cms, product-management

I am currently working on a website, that aims at showcasing photography products of a certain brand, and with the following features:

- General listings of products per categories (cameras, lenses, accessories...)
- Advanced search (similar to Amazon and most e-commerce website, to target for instance wide-angle lenses, zooms, ultra-zooms...)
- A dedicated page for each product (showing pictures, links to reviews, tech specs, description, user reviews...)
- If possible a comparison functionality, to compare several products based on tech specs

I could develop such website from scratch, but it's a huge investment in time. I would like to know if there are existing CMS that allow this kind of website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMS, [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/), uses many modules to provide those types of capabilities.  One that I’ve used for paid digital downloads is [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart).  Ubercart provides many features including:

**Current Features**:

- Configurable product catalog includes catalog pages and a block to
  display product categories.
- Flexible product creation system with product classes.
- Multiple product image support out of the box.
- Flexible product attributes system
- Basic product stock level tracking and notification.
- Product features to add file downloads, role promotions, and more to
  products.
- Single page checkout.
- Automatic account generation (anonymous checkout).
- Customer and administrator checkout notifications.
- Simple order processing (with workflow for automated order
  processing).
- Simple order creation and editing.
- Integrated payment system that acts as a bridge between acceptable
  payment methods (check, credit card, purchase order, etc.) and
  payment gateways (CyberSource, Authorize.net, PayPal, etc.).
- Shipping quotes and fulfillment, including integration with UPS,
  FedEx, USPS.
- Sales, product, and customer reports.
- Activity logging.

And, for those features that may be lacking, you can easily add your own code, or, create views of the requested data.

Comment: Thanks rrirower! It looks like it answers my need :)

Answer (score 0):

Many e-commerce plugins or extensions in WordPress, Joomla and other content management systems include the required features:

```
✅️ product listings
✅️ categories
✅️ advanced search and filtering
✅️ product detail page
✅️ product comparison
```

and these can usually be set to catalogue mode if you don't need all the e-commerce features.

A solution that allows you to add product custom fields may help if there are many product features you want website visitors to compare.